# How to implement diagnostic switching of power transistors in the three phase voltage source inverter?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, power-electronics, control, induction-motor

I have been developing a control software for the three phase voltage source inverter.

[image]

For diagnostic purposes I would like to include a special operating mode of the control software in which I can test individual transistors \$(S_1-S_6)\$ in the inverter via switching them without current loading.

My idea is to write a special service application running on a laptop and via its graphical user interface select one of the six transistors. Based on that selection the control software at first transits into the "diagnostic" operating mode and then will start generate firing pulses for the chosen transistor.

My first idea how to implement this diagnostic feature at the control software level was to use the standard pwm peripheral of my MCU and configure it for the center aligned mode. Then in the diagnostic mode set a output mask for chosen transistor and set some appropriate fix value of the duty cycle.

Do you think that the simple solution I have described above is usable? Can you tell me how to determine the fix value of the duty cycle?

Comment: How will you tell if that transistor is switching if it's the only one switched on. No current will flow.

Comment: According to the status of the LED on the driver circuit.

Comment: OK. That might be of some use. Why are you worried about a "fix value"? Why not just turn on it on 100% or, better again, fade from 0 to 100% and back to 0 in a repeating pattern?

Comment: PWM outputs are usually also GPIO outputs, with a control register to switch between functions. So why not turn them into GPIO outputs for this test? (Ensuring you never enable more than one at a time).